# How was each chapter in the bible divided into sections?

Tags: bible, versification

I was wondering how each chapter in the bible was divided into sections (a sub-chapter group of verses)?

Is division of a chapter into sections subjective to

- the translation version?
- the author of the translation?

For example, consider Chapter "Romans 3".
A KJV version (Published by Thomas Nelson Publishers with ePub Edition December 2022: 978-1-400-33350-9) divided the chapter into four sections titled as:

- Gods Judgment Defended
- All Have Sinned
- Gods Righteousness Through Faith
- Boasting Excluded

whereas an ESV version (Published by Crossway in 2001) did it differently into only three sections:

- Gods Righteousness Upheld
- No One Is Righteous
- The Righteousness of God Through Faith

The first two sections were titled differently in the two versions.
"The Righteousness of God Through Faith" in the ESV version is exactly the combination of "Gods Righteousness Through Faith" and "Boasting Excluded" in the KJV version.

Why is there a difference?

Comment: I took out the parts that one might find subjective - I don't believe the subheads are inspired in any way (except maybe in psalms) so I think just asking why there's a difference is good enough - there's probably no good answer as to which is better (do you like things wordier?).

Comment: I like things organized better.